# Manual page synopsis conventions, eg. rename(1)

Tags: unix

I am trying to understand the synopsis section of manual pages, for example for the rename command it is:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> rename [ -h|-m|-V ] [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] [ -e|-E perlexpr]*|perlexpr [ files ]

I have not been able to find out what the asterisk means in the synopsis.

As `*|perlexpr` is not enclosed in square brackets I imagine it is mandatory. If that is true then presumably calling the command to get the version (`rename -V`) which does not require `*|perlexpr` is not being considered. Am I correct about that?

In the description section they give this example: `rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *`

I suspected the asterisk at the end of that example corresponds to the asterisk I mentioned in the synopsis although I now think it more likely it is the optional *files* argument and has nothing to do with the asterisk in the synopsis. I can not see from the documentation what the asterisk in the synopsis does or means. Am I correct in assuming that the pipe character after the asterisk in the synopsis means you can either use an asterisk or a perlexpr?

Does the Synopsis have a way of indicating where order (of arguments and options) matters and where it does not?

Any help on understanding this (I have done some googling and had a look at man's man page but am still confused) would be really appreciated.

Comment: These are not Bash's manual pages. I guess you are trying to ask about the manual pages for individual commands.

Comment: Anyway, it's not like this is a well-defined convention. This particular manual page seems to favor a BNF-like syntax to indicate one or more repetitions of something; this should be familiar to many programmers, but of course, if you haven't encountered BNF, it's hard to make sense of.

Comment: The `*` in the example is most definitely a literal wildcard character which the shell expands to an alphabetic listing of all the non-dot files in the current directory.

Comment: I *think* there is a bug which you have corr ctly identified; the `--version` option should de"initely not require the otherwise required arguments.

Comment: Thanks. that sheds some light and also I have take note of your edits for future reference. I am still unsure what the asterix in the synopsis is trying to tell me.

Comment: The `-e` or `-E perlexpr` options are optional. The `-E perlexpr` can be repeated. If both are absent, the first argument is considered to be a `perlexpr` (otherwise it is the first file to operate on.

Comment: So the asterix means the preceeding `[ -e|-E perlexpr]` can be repeated. I had not realised that.  At the top of the man page it sais RENAME(1p). What does 1p relate to? Also, if it said 1 (instead of 1p) would that indicate that it is a Bash manual page or at least a manual page about a bash page (that is how I understood the man page for man which sais 1 means "Executable programs or shell commands"). In the example, `rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *` is there just one perl expression which is `y/A-Z/a-z/`?

Comment: That's still spelled *asterisk.* Asterix is a comic (the name of the protagonist is a play on the word asterisk).

Comment: `1p` very vaguely indicates an associaltion with Perl; this is a command (section 1) which is part of the Perl package (which uses the `p` suffix for its manual pages). Bash is also a command but most commands (and thus most manual pages in section 1) don't care which shell you use, and will work without a shell if you are in a place where you have that option.

Comment: A vague convention in manual pages is to provide several `SYNOPSIS` alternatives on separate lines; this is one way to precisely but succinctly express mutually exclusive sets of options. The normal expectation is that ordering of optional arguments is free; you would at least expect the prose `DESCRIPTION` section to spell out any deviations from common conventions.

Comment: I was just thinking that such an approach would be helpful. I can see in the case of options like  -help, -man and -version it is obvious that you would not be using any of the following options or arguments. In other cases it is not so obvious. A slightly less obvious case is that presumably one would never use the -force and -nono options together. I think it would be extremely useful if the documentation could make all this unambiguous. When one does understand it it seems pointless but when one does not understand it it is useful to see which are the valid use cases.